# Getting issue on the image while updating the records in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I have a form and fields are `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `profile_pic` . I am able to insert the data in the database.

For example, I added data

```
first_name:xyz
middle_name:poiu
last_name:wertfg
profile_pic:abcvd.png
```

Now I am on the edit page, I fetch all the data from the database and displaying on the edit page. I have to update the records. So I added

```
first_name:12kjh
middle_name:12lkiuy
last_name:96lkjhg
```

**Note:**: I haven't added the image.

I am getting the issue on `profile_pic`. Profile_pic is also updating and getting the empty in the database.

I have to check if there is already image on profile_pic. If yes then update the same name if no then adds a new image or else send empty if user not adding an image.

What condition I have to use?
**Controller**

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            { 
    //some validation error code
            } else {
//Get Last Image Name
        $get_image_name = $this->List_model->getImageName($id);
      echo $get_image_name //getting image name


            $config=[
                    'upload_path'   =>'./uploads/images',
                    'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
                    'file_name'     =>uniqid().time().date("dmy")
                    ]; 
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic'))
                     {
                      $profile_pic_set = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                     }
                     else{
                           $profile_pic_set = "";
                        }
                $updateData= array(
                'first_name'    => trim($this->input->post('first_name')),
                'middle_name'   => trim($this->input->post('middle_name')),
                'last_name'     => trim($this->input->post('last_name')),
                'profile_pic'   => $profile_pic_set,
            );

               $secure_updateData = $this->security->xss_clean($updateData);
               if($secure_updateData)
                    {
                        $this->db->where('member_id', $id);
                        $this->db->update('members', $secure_updateData);

                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['msg']   = "Member Successfully Saved";
                   echo json_encode($response);
                    }else{
                        alert("Sometning wrong! please check the internet connection and try again");
                    }          
            }
```

Comment: You could put it in short notation 
'profile_pic' => ($this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic') !=NULL)?$this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic'):''

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the updated data,ensure there is a file or not

```
$updateData= array(
        'first_name'    => trim($this->input->post('first_name')),
        'middle_name'   => trim($this->input->post('middle_name')),
        'last_name'     => trim($this->input->post('last_name')),
        'profile_pic'   => '',  
);
if(!file_exists($_FILES['profile_pic']['tmp_name'])) {
   unset($updateData['profile_pic']);
}else{
    $config=[
           'upload_path'   =>'./uploads/images',
           'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
           'file_name'     =>uniqid().time().date("dmy")
           ]; 
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     if ($this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic')){
          $updateData['profile_pic_set'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
     }else{
          $updateData['profile_pic_set'] = "";
     } 
}
    //UPDATE YOUR DATA HERE
$secure_updateData = $this->security->xss_clean($updateData);
if($secure_updateData){
   $this->db->where('member_id', $id);
   $this->db->update('members', $secure_updateData);
   $response['error'] = true;
   $response['msg']   = "Member Successfully Saved";
   echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think your answer is increasing the number of lines. I mean in case I have more than 10 fields that I have to write twice according to your answer.